# How to make a python program to convert a bunch of pdfs to html?

Tags: html, windows, python-2.7, pdf, converters

I was trying to do a program that would read all the pdfs in a folder and convert all of them to htmls, for example file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf then run the program and create something like file1.html, file2.html, file3.htm. Without losing the main pdf of course, untill now I only could do it to one file, I don't how to make for every file on the folder with a loop.
Here's my code:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
#bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdf2htmlEX\\pdf2htmlEX.exe'
#if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
#    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
#    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("pdf2txt.py -o %s.html %s" %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
```

Comment: You need to pass `--dest-dir` to `pdf2htmlEX`.

Comment: It still didn't work, how do I do that change, sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Your `base_directory` is wrong. You need to use two backslashes for Windows paths. If you get the `base_directory` wrong, nothing will happen because `os.walk` will not return any results.

Comment: I've changed to doublebackslash and it still says that Windows couldn't find the specified file

Comment: I tried on 3 different PC's and it didn't work in any, changing the path of course, here's the print of the error: https://gyazo.com/032c0eff0a2526f885aa81eb387f0423
The last line of the error means "Windows couldn't  find the specified file or directory" (My PC is in Portuguese)

Comment: You need to provide the full path to `pdf2htmlEX`.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: In what directory is it located?

Comment: C:\Python27\pdf2htmlEX-master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete solution that uses [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX):

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\learningpython\\PROJECT'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdf2htmlEX-master\\pdf2htmlEX.exe'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, dir_path, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("%s --dest-dir %s %s" % args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did as you said but know the program runs with no errors but it doesn't do anything

Comment: It still doesn't happen anything, I run the code, there are no errors, but it doesn't convert anything

Comment: I modified the code to print an error message and exit if `base_directory` does not exist.

Comment: It keeps saying that windows couldn't find the specified file: https://gyazo.com/2eeb5b3f95f22f989a9a98f209caf59e

Comment: I modified the code to use the full path to `pdf2htmlEX`.

Comment: It return the same error, is it possible that the pdf2htmlEX isn't correctly installed? How can I check it?

Comment: I did it, I have an exe that I run from the cmd, I pasted It's path to the path you told me and it still gives me the same error, I'll update my code

Comment: I modified the code to print an error message and exit if `bin_path` does not exist.

Comment: It didn't print the error you wrote, instead it gave the same error, here's the print of the error: https://gyazo.com/7d27604980cbe05700d65ad230aeceeb

Comment: I modified the code so that it doesn't call `shlex.split` on Windows.

Comment: It is working well, I tried with 3 pdfs in the same folder and it converted 2 of them, the third said "Could not read the file" but that may be a problem on the pdf right?

Comment: Without looking at the traceback, I can't confirm that.

Comment: Ok, I noticed another problema, it converter but the HTML file has all of the text that was on the PDF file encripted, its like its never been there, I tried to convert one file with pdfminer(pdf2txt.py) instead pdf2html and the text didn't got corrupted, is there any way Tô chance that on this program? Or desencrypt or change to use pdfminer?

Comment: You can change the program to use `pdfminer`. Just change what you pass to the `run` function.

Comment: I changed and It returned me this error: https://gyazo.com/8db03c49b7f8f0de8a87c83080ff2e29?token=4ce00bce38a697905907713ff3798ee2
I updated my code

Comment: You need to add `python` to your command: `run("python pdf2txt.py -o %s.html %s" % args)`. You might have to provide the full path to `python` if it's not in your `PATH`.

Comment: ok it is fully working, at first it didn't convert pdfs that had spaces on the name, I updated the code to remove all the spaces from the pdfs, now I just need to change the output directory (where the .html will go) because it is going to the folder where the program is running, how can I do that?

Comment: I think you can figure that out on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm needing help to a second part of this program, which is list all the tags PA/ and the characters nex to it that are inside of the html created, could you help me out? here's the new post about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629600/how-to-list-all-strings-that-have-a-pa-inside-of-a-html-file-using-beatiful-sou

Answer (score 0):

to compile pdf2html project by https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX, and system call cmd pdf2html by python

Comment: I did the changes an it still didn't worked, I swaped "subprocess.call(["pdf2txt.py", "-o", "output.html", content])" for "subprocess.call(["pdf2htmlEX", content]) #to convert every file on path to .html"