# How to list all strings that have a PA/ inside of a html file using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, pdf, beautifulsoup, converters

I have a program that converts pdfs into html and I needed to complement this program so after converting It would search for the tags PA/ and the character in front of it and save these tags and characters to a CSV file, I'm trying to do it but I can't.

Here's the code so far:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
            continue
        with open(file_name) as markup:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
            text = soup.get_text()
            match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)\s*(\S*)", text)
            print(match)
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows('%s' %match)
```

The html is too big, I'll write here a part of it that includes the PA's and the text that I don't want:

```
<html>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34023px; width:84px; height:32px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Bold; font-size:17px">JUST SOME TEXT THAT I DON'T WANT TO HAVE ON THE CSV FILE
        <br></span><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/00986/17 GTD
        <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34066px; width:84px; height:16px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/01008/17 GTD
        <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34105px; width:84px; height:16px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/01095/17 GTD
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add html

Comment: I have edited and added a part of the html file that contains the parts I want and the parts I don't want

Comment: Specify the error that you are getting while writting to CSV

Comment: https://gyazo.com/34a54f68f08a8594ee9b7c18ea2f0e9a

Comment: I updated my code and now it doesn't prompt a error, but it doesn't write what I wanted aswell, could you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check Online Demo](https://repl.it/H141/1)

```
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    html_doc = """
    <html>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <body>
            <div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34023px; width:84px; height:32px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Bold; font-size:17px">JUST SOME TEXT THAT I DON'T WANT TO HAVE ON THE CSV FILE
            <br></span><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/00986/17 GTD
            <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34066px; width:84px; height:16px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/01008/17 GTD
            <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:59px; top:34105px; width:84px; height:16px;"><span style="font-family: YFEHEP+Times-Roman; font-size:16px">PA/01095/17 GTD
        </body>
    </html>
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()

    match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)\s*(\S*)", text)
    print(match)
```

For writting to CSV

```
import csv
with open('ur file.csv','wb') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['fist_col','second_col'])
    for row in match:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Ok, that worked, but what if the html is too big? should I still paste it or can I use the name of the file to look for it? And if there are multiple html on a folder and I want to search on all of them? Sorry for so many questions I'm new to coding

Comment: There is no pattern in your HTML ; like there is no common class to the element you want to find.You have to search in the entire html body.If you can provide full HTML then it is easy to find pattern.If your HTML is 1-3mb  then there is no issue

Comment: But I have to do this to a lot of htmls, doind that by hand, copying and pasting would take a lot of time, isn't there a way to say "look on the body of every one of this files and search for PA/..."?

Comment: Yes, you can get all HTML files in a directory with python then iterate the above code over them

Comment: Yeah, I did it and I think it worked, now how can I save this information that as the value "match" to a csv file? I tried but it prompted me an error, I updated my code

Comment: I upvoted but It says that I need 15 reputation, how do I save match to a csv file?